# { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" } i am trying to get a access token and refresh token

Tags: google-sheets, access-token, refresh-token

i am trying to get a access token and refresh token to access google sheets data but every time i try to get a token i get the same error "invalid grant type" i am using grant type authorization code. i am trying to get a access token using postman and it worked but its not working in my pycharm.

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("oauth2.googleapis.com")
payload = 'code=<your code here>A&client_id=<your client id>&client_secret=<your client secret>redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2F&grant_type=authorization_code'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
conn.request("POST", "/token", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

i tried this and i tried to get token through request also

```
import requests

url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

payload='code=<your-code-here>%0A&client_id=<your client id>&client_secret=<your client secret>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fgsheet&grant_type=authorization_code'
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMC0nVvV0m77pPvgNLnWXopI7VKvoBdVSDSgvi6Fx0mrPYQf9xU6j3UJCA3vrWRi62Tqfv0PFZd9uo59C2NQzraV1MBtAAF1G_tTRXIXELxsbmjf5weGJ6FkmJknDof2riZCnpYzK-J2EWmWKQVeetwd',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Try adding "&" symbol before "redirect_uri" in the first snippet:
"..<your client secret>redirect_uri.." There's no & in your code.

Comment: when i was removing client id and client secret it got removed but its present in my actual code

Comment: Try printing out the generated request uri and test it using postman !

Comment: by using postman its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The method (.request) definition is like this:

HTTPConnection.request(method, url, body=None, headers={}, *, encode_chunked=False)

And your arguments doesn't match!

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request